# How to mock RestTemplate exchange?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit

I want to unit test assignApplicationsToUser. A list of applicationId and user id is given and I have a URL to validate a user. I am getting an exception mentioned below.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode.asText()" because the return value of "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode.get(String)" is null
```

AssignmentService.java

```
public class AssignmentService implements AssignemetServiceInterface {
    @Autowired
    AppInterceptor appInterceptor;
    @Autowired
    AssignmentRepository assignmentRepository;
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private String uri="http://localhost:8080/api/users/"+uuid;

    @Override
    public List<String> assignApplicationsToUser(List<String> applications, String uuid)
            throws SQLException, RequestEntityNotFoundException {

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("token", appInterceptor.getLoggedInUser());
        HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(null, headers);
        String result = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, String.class).getBody();

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        List<String> response = new ArrayList<>();
        JsonNode responseJson = objectMapper.readTree(result);
        if (responseJson.get("data") == null
                    && responseJson.get("error").get("status").asText().equals("NOT_FOUND")) {
                throw new RequestEntityNotFoundException(uuid, "find");
        }

        for (String application : applications) {
        ApplicationAssignment isAssigned = assignmentRepository.findOneByApplicationId(application);
            if (isAssigned != null) {
                isAssigned.setIsUser(true);
                response.add(application + " reassigned to "+ uuid);
                isAssigned.setAssignedTo(uuid);
                this.assignmentRepository.save(isAssigned);
                } 
           else {
          ApplicationAssignment newApplication = new ApplicationAssignment(application, uuid, true);
    
            this.assignmentRepository.save(newApplication);
            response.add(application + " assigned successfully");
        }
       }
    return response;
}
}
```

sample input:
{
applications :["APP001","APP002","APP003","APP004"],
uuid : "user1"
}

**Edited :**
I have added sample response for the same.

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "fa727274-5a74-428a-b0f6-501eebafd8e8",
        "name": "Akash",
        "email": "AkashTyagi@fico.com",
        "phone": 8799190991,
        "isActive": true,
        "createdBy": "abhishekjaiswal@fico.com",
        "updatedBy": null,
        "creationTimeStamp": "2021-08-11T11:23:05.356+00:00",
        "updationTimeStamp": null
    },
    "error": null,
    "timeStamp": "2021-08-16T05:02:04.866+00:00",
    "success": true
}
```

AssignmentServiceTest.java

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class AssignmentServiceTest {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AssignmentServiceTest.class);
    @InjectMocks
    private AssignmentService assignmentService;
    
    @Mock
    private AssignmentRepository assignmentRepo;
    
    @Mock
    private AppInterceptor appInterceptor;
    
    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    
    ObjectMapper  objectMapper;
    String jsonString="{\r\n"
            + "    \"data\": {\r\n"
            + "        \"id\": \"fa727274-5a74-428a-b0f6-501eebafd8e8\",\r\n"
            + "        \"name\": \"Akash\",\r\n"
            + "        \"email\": \"AkashTyagi@fico.com\",\r\n"
            + "        \"phone\": 8799190991,\r\n"
            + "        \"isActive\": true,\r\n"
            + "        \"createdBy\": \"abhishekjaiswal@fico.com\",\r\n"
            + "        \"updatedBy\": null,\r\n"
            + "        \"creationTimeStamp\": \"2021-08-11T11:23:05.356+00:00\",\r\n"
            + "        \"updationTimeStamp\": null\r\n"
            + "    },\r\n"
            + "    \"error\": null,\r\n"
            + "    \"timeStamp\": \"2021-08-16T05:02:04.866+00:00\",\r\n"
            + "    \"success\": true\r\n"
            + "}";;
            
    JsonNode mock;
    
    @BeforeEach
    private void setUp() throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
    
         objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
         mock = org.mockito.Mockito.mock(JsonNode.class);
    }
    @Test
    public void test_assignApplicationsToUser() throws NullPointerException, SQLException, RequestEntityNotFoundException, IndexOutOfBoundsException,JsonProcessingException, URISyntaxException{

        LOGGER.info("Begin of test_assignApplicationToUser method");

        
        ApplicationAssignment applicationAssignment = new ApplicationAssignment("1","u1",true);
        ApplicationAssignment savedApplicationAssignment = new ApplicationAssignment("1","u2",true);
    

        ResponseEntity<String> myEntity = new ResponseEntity<String>("{\r\"error\":null\r}",HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
        
        
        Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(
                ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),
                ArgumentMatchers.any(HttpMethod.class),
                ArgumentMatchers.any(),
                ArgumentMatchers.<Class<String>>any())).thenReturn(myEntity);
        
        Mockito.when(appInterceptor.getLoggedInUser()).thenReturn("abhishek@fico.com");

     
        Mockito.when(mock.get("data")).thenReturn(mock);
        Mockito.when(mock.get("error")).thenReturn(mock);
        Mockito.when(mock.get("error").asText()).thenReturn("FOUND");
        LOGGER.info("Node value "+ mock.asText());
        
        Mockito.when(assignmentRepo.findOneByApplicationId("1")).thenReturn(applicationAssignment);
        Mockito.when(assignmentRepo.save(ArgumentMatchers.any())).thenReturn(savedApplicationAssignment);
 
        // Mock the input List of applications
        List<String> listOfApplication = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfApplication.add("app1");
        listOfApplication.add("app2");
        List<String> response = assignmentService.assignApplicationsToUser(listOfApplication,"u1");
        assertEquals(response.get(0),"app1 assigned successfully");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In main code, create two pojos as below which would represent response of the rest call.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class UserDataResponse {

    @JsonProperty("data")
    UserInfo userInfo;

    @JsonProperty("error")
    String error;

    @JsonProperty("success")
    boolean success;


}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class UserInfo {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    String id;

    @JsonProperty("name")
    String name;

    @JsonProperty("email")
    String email;

    @JsonProperty("phone")
    String phone;

    @JsonProperty("isActive")
    boolean isActive;

    @JsonProperty("createdBy")
    String createdBy;

    @JsonProperty("updatedBy")
    String updatedBy;
}
```

In AssignmentService class change your code to get the response as below since this is better way to handle the rest response based on the HttpStatus code rather than trying to element in the json. So your main rest call would look like as below:

```
        String result = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, String.class);

        if(result.getStatusCode()==HttpStatus.OK){
            UserDataResponse userDataResponse = readResponse(result,UserDataResponse.class);
            
        }else if(result.getStatusCode()==HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND){
            throw new RequestEntityNotFoundException(uuid, "find");
        }

// You can make below code as part of the helper class and use it anywhere you want.
      private <T> T readResponse(ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity,Class<T> classType){
        T object;
        try {
                object = objectMapper.readValue(responseEntity.getBody(),classType);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Testing Code:
Mock all the variables of service like AppInterceptor, repository and resttemplate to be injectto AssignmentService.
Put all the below code in test class like AssingmentServiceTest

```
    @Mock
    AppInterceptor appInterceptor;

    @Mock
    AssignmentRepository assignmentRepository;

    @Mock
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @InjectMocks
    AssignmentService assignmentService;

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Test
    public void test_assignApplicationsToUser(){

        UserDataResponse restResponse = new UserDataResponse();
        String jsonString="{\r\n"
                + "    \"data\": {\r\n"
                + "        \"id\": \"fa727274-5a74-428a-b0f6-501eebafd8e8\",\r\n"
                + "        \"name\": \"Akash\",\r\n"
                + "        \"email\": \"AkashTyagi@fico.com\",\r\n"
                + "        \"phone\": 8799190991,\r\n"
                + "        \"isActive\": true,\r\n"
                + "        \"createdBy\": \"abhishekjaiswal@fico.com\",\r\n"
                + "        \"updatedBy\": null,\r\n"
                + "        \"creationTimeStamp\": \"2021-08-11T11:23:05.356+00:00\",\r\n"
                + "        \"updationTimeStamp\": null\r\n"
                + "    },\r\n"
                + "    \"error\": null,\r\n"
                + "    \"timeStamp\": \"2021-08-16T05:02:04.866+00:00\",\r\n"
                + "    \"success\": true\r\n"
                + "}";

        restResponse = readResponse(jsonString, UserDataResponse.class);
        ResponseEntity<String> myEntity = new ResponseEntity<String>(restResponse.toString(),HttpStatus.OK);
        Mockito.when(resttemplate.exchange(
                ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),
                ArgumentMatchers.any(HttpMethod.class),
                ArgumentMatchers.any(),
                ArgumentMatchers.<Class<String>>any())
    ).thenReturn(myEntity);

        // You can create a ApplicationAssignment pojo and pass it in thenReturn
        ApplicationAssignment applicationAssignment = new ApplicationAssingment(1,"sd");
        Mockito.when(assignmentRepository.findOneByApplicationId(ArgumentMatchers.any())).thenReturn(assignmentRepository);

        Mockito.when(appInterceptor.getLoggedInUser).thenReturn("token");

        // You can mock the response here but looks like that response is not used anywhere
        ApplicationAssignment savedApplicationAssignment = new ApplicationAssignment(1,"ss");
        Mockito.when(assignmentRepository.save(ArgumentMatchers.any())).thenReturn(savedApplicationAssignment);

        // Mock the input List of applications
        List<String> listOfApplication = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfApplication.add("app1");
        listOfApplication.add("app2");
        List<String> response = assignmentService.assignApplicationsToUser(listOfApplication,"1212");
        assertEquals(response[0],"app1 reassigned to 1212");
  }
```

Comment: Getting an exception 
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('e' (code 101)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
 at [Source: (String)"{exists:true}"; line: 1, column: 3]

Comment: I changed as per given exception to "{\r\"exists\":true\r}" and now getting below exception.
Cannot invoke "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode.get(String)" because the return value of "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode.get(String)" is null

Comment: you can create a model class for the response of the rest call. mock that object and expect it as the response. can you provide a sample response from the rest call?

Comment: Please find updated code above. Also i believe
 Mockito.when(mock.get("data")).thenReturn(mock);
        Mockito.when(mock.get("error")).thenReturn(mock);
        Mockito.when(mock.get("error").asText()).thenReturn("FOUND");
        LOGGER.info("Node value "+ mock.asText());

these lines are not required

Comment: I am trying to test the below-mentioned branch. 

 if (responseJson.get("data") == null
                    && responseJson.get("error") != null ){
                throw new RequestEntityNotFoundException(uuid, "find");
    }

Comment: as i have mentioned in code above.. it is better to handle that like below:

'if(result.getStatusCode()==HttpStatus.OK){
            UserDataResponse userDataResponse = readResponse(result,UserDataResponse.class);
            
        }else if(result.getStatusCode()==HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND){
            throw new RequestEntityNotFoundException(uuid, "find");
        }'

Comment: you cannot both the happy and error scenario in the one test case.. write another test cases which tests the RequestEntityNotFoundException. This can be achieved by not setting "data" to null in the mocked responseentity